# Impact of creating calculated fields in Workday

Tags: workday-api

What is the impact of creating calculated fields in Workday
Will it make Workday slower, if this is slower how we can avoid to make some changes specially for integration ?

Is it better to have a report based calculated fields. If Yes, then will it impact on the report only ?

Is Workday doesn't calculated field OR they have any special recommendation on this ?

Asif

Answer (score 0):

It, the calculated field, doesn't make Workday as a whole slower, not in any noticeable way anyway. If your calculated fields are complex, that can sometimes make the report run slower. Try using report filters when you can if you find the calculated field slowing things up. It's possible a lot of long running reports might slow your system down some; you can contact Workday for that question.

As far as report based calculated fields vs global calculated fields: only use the global calculated fields if you think you will reuse them in more than one report, otherwise, use the report calculated fields. Make sure you have a good naming convention for your calculated fields; the more you have, it can get hard to keep track of them all. But whether your calculated field is report-based or global, they both perform the same way, one isn't slower than the other.

Answer (score 0):

Report performance is not based on calculated fields. It completely depends on the Datasource and business object you are using within the report.

Answer (score 0):

Report running performance is completely depends on the Datasource and business object what we using in Report. But sometimes we will create calculated field to fetch specific data instead of changing datasource or business object. During this time performance will affect.

1. Maximum we need to give importance to use workday delivered field.
2. Check Report run time for various Business Object and Datasource
3. Try to use indexed datasource
4. consider or try to use Optimized Performance check box for choosing BO or Datasource while creating report